# Adding text to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, escaping

I tried adding this text to the MySQL database with PHP and the $_POST method:

HTML:

```
<form name="addBook" action="?action=save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Boek naam</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='book_name'  required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Genre</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='book_genre'  required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cover</td>
            <td><input type='file' name='cover' id='cover'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td><textarea cols='50' rows='20' name='book_text'>Schrijf hier</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Remove text">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
$query = $db->prepare("
                INSERT INTO `books` (`book_name`, `book_text`, `book_genre`, `book_cover`) VALUES (:name, :text, :genre, :fulldir)");
    $query->bindParam(':name', $book_name);
    $query->bindParam(':text', $book_text);
    $query->bindParam(':genre', $book_genre);
    $query->bindParam(':fulldir', $fulldir);
    $query->execute();
```

This is the text:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nec metus eget enim egestas rhoncus. Cras id suscipit augue. Mauris dignissim semper ligula, non rhoncus mi sollicitudin sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas non augue eu augue ultrices commodo a accumsan magna. Sed luctus nulla libero. Ut vitae felis eu nunc porttitor fermentum at porta felis. Curabitur pulvinar, tortor ut gravida facilisis, eros lectus condimentum metus, cursus dapibus sapien lacus vel nisl. Maecenas rutrum nunc eget convallis imperdiet. Fusce felis ex, vehicula placerat erat ut, eleifend consequat dolor. Vestibulum fringilla elementum ante, fringilla luctus elit faucibus eget.
>
> Etiam ac enim non nisl elementum dapibus vel quis augue. Sed vestibulum, lacus vitae ultricies dictum, lacus augue sodales justo, sit amet efficitur purus neque vitae magna. Duis malesuada sagittis tortor, in commodo nisi hendrerit ut. Quisque quis tincidunt odio. Ut cursus enim nec venenatis laoreet. Vestibulum erat diam, egestas vitae scelerisque sed, pulvinar a turpis. Curabitur odio justo, ornare eget tortor eu, commodo condimentum est. Nam dictum, augue tempor dictum porttitor, mi turpis volutpat eros, a tristique metus ipsum nec enim."

But when I add the text, it removes the whitespace between the two paragraphs:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nec metus eget enim egestas rhoncus. Cras id suscipit augue. Mauris dignissim semper ligula, non rhoncus mi sollicitudin sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas non augue eu augue ultrices commodo a accumsan magna. Sed luctus nulla libero. Ut vitae felis eu nunc porttitor fermentum at porta felis. Curabitur pulvinar, tortor ut gravida facilisis, eros lectus condimentum metus, cursus dapibus sapien lacus vel nisl. Maecenas rutrum nunc eget convallis imperdiet. Fusce felis ex, vehicula placerat erat ut, eleifend consequat dolor. Vestibulum fringilla elementum ante, fringilla luctus elit faucibus eget. Etiam ac enim non nisl elementum dapibus vel quis augue. Sed vestibulum, lacus vitae ultricies dictum, lacus augue sodales justo, sit amet efficitur purus neque vitae magna. Duis malesuada sagittis tortor, in commodo nisi hendrerit ut. Quisque quis tincidunt odio. Ut cursus enim nec venenatis laoreet. Vestibulum erat diam, egestas vitae scelerisque sed, pulvinar a turpis. Curabitur odio justo, ornare eget tortor eu, commodo condimentum est. Nam dictum, augue tempor dictum porttitor, mi turpis volutpat eros, a tristique metus ipsum nec enim."

How can I add the text to the database, while keeping the whitespace between paragraphs?

Comment: How are you writing this to the database now?  How have you confirmed that whitespace is being removed?  The database is going to store whatever stream of character data it's given, it doesn't strip out specific characters.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with PHP? Is it from $_POST? Is it from phpmyadmin? More info please... noone can understand your question.

Comment: put a debug statement before inserting to db. Check that it have new line (\n) in it. If it is there then it will write the same in db. If it is not there it will not write. and This will join all lines

Comment: Yes, I'm adding the text with PHP and the $_POST method.

Comment: @AliShahid: Instead of vaguely trying to describe your code, maybe you can actually show code which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Are you viewing the output in a browser? You might need to use the `nl2br`.

Comment: Seems very likely to be that the _browser_ you're viewing it in is collapsing the whitespace. http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: How do I use the nl2br function?

Comment: @DaveH: There was a clash of two edits. By accepting the suggested edit, you killed the code provided by the OP. I did a rollback and reapplied your changes and that of the suggested edit. Please be a bit more careful next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new line character `\n` won't display in a browser. You need to convert them to `<br>`s. This can be done using [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) either on the data insert or on the output. For example:

```
$query = $db->prepare("
                INSERT INTO `books` (`book_name`, `book_text`, `book_genre`, `book_cover`) VALUES (:name, :text, :genre, :fulldir)");
    $query->bindParam(':name', $book_name);
    $query->bindParam(':text', nl2br($book_text));
    $query->bindParam(':genre', $book_genre);
    $query->bindParam(':fulldir', $fulldir);
    $query->execute();
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac2f35000833f6c91e2d96bf10a09b96ea182ae8

or on the output method...

```
echo nl2br($row['book_text']);
```

Comment: You should not use `nl2br()` in `bindParam()`. It is generally not recommended to modify data before inserting it. Instead you should use the second method, insert it in its original unmodified format and use `nl2br()` only on output.  Changing it before storing it can cause problems later when attempting searches for example.

Answer (score -1):

Here the Inster for this text. Change the tablename and the Fieldname.

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`fieldname`)
VALUES
    ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nec metus eget enim egestas rhoncus. Cras id suscipit augue. Mauris dignissim semper ligula, non rhoncus mi sollicitudin sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas non augue eu augue ultrices commodo a accumsan magna. Sed luctus nulla libero. Ut vitae felis eu nunc porttitor fermentum at porta felis. Curabitur pulvinar, tortor ut gravida facilisis, eros lectus condimentum metus, cursus dapibus sapien lacus vel nisl. Maecenas rutrum nunc eget convallis imperdiet. Fusce felis ex, vehicula placerat erat ut, eleifend consequat dolor. Vestibulum fringilla elementum ante, fringilla luctus elit faucibus eget.\n\nEtiam ac enim non nisl elementum dapibus vel quis augue. Sed vestibulum, lacus vitae ultricies dictum, lacus augue sodales justo, sit amet efficitur purus neque vitae magna. Duis malesuada sagittis tortor, in commodo nisi hendrerit ut. Quisque quis tincidunt odio. Ut cursus enim nec venenatis laoreet. Vestibulum erat diam, egestas vitae scelerisque sed, pulvinar a turpis. Curabitur odio justo, ornare eget tortor eu, commodo condimentum est. Nam dictum, augue tempor dictum porttitor, mi turpis volutpat eros, a tristique metus ipsum nec enim.\"\n\nBut when I add the text, it removes the whitespace between the two paragraphs:\n\n\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nec metus eget enim egestas rhoncus. Cras id suscipit augue. Mauris dignissim semper ligula, non rhoncus mi sollicitudin sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas non augue eu augue ultrices commodo a accumsan magna. Sed luctus nulla libero. Ut vitae felis eu nunc porttitor fermentum at porta felis. Curabitur pulvinar, tortor ut gravida facilisis, eros lectus condimentum metus, cursus dapibus sapien lacus vel nisl. Maecenas rutrum nunc eget convallis imperdiet. Fusce felis ex, vehicula placerat erat ut, eleifend consequat dolor. Vestibulum fringilla elementum ante, fringilla luctus elit faucibus eget. Etiam ac enim non nisl elementum dapibus vel quis augue. Sed vestibulum, lacus vitae ultricies dictum, lacus augue sodales justo, sit amet efficitur purus neque vitae magna. Duis malesuada sagittis tortor, in commodo nisi hendrerit ut. Quisque quis tincidunt odio. Ut cursus enim nec venenatis laoreet. Vestibulum erat diam, egestas vitae scelerisque sed, pulvinar a turpis. Curabitur odio justo, ornare eget tortor eu, commodo condimentum est. Nam dictum, augue tempor dictum porttitor, mi turpis volutpat eros, a tristique metus ipsum nec enim');
```

Comment: How does this resolve the issue? The data is inserting, it is missing the linebreaks (or supposedly).