# MySQL varchar and linebreak only works on textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got a DB entry with a varchar field with the following text saved:

```
This is a line
new line here
and another line here
```

I can only see those line breaks if I print it within `textarea`. How can I make the line break work outside of textarea?

Comment: Use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) or print the text in a `<pre>` block.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've tried both and they were failing that's why I posted here but it seems like I was editing the wrong file like 30' now -.-" tyvm!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding text to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768291/adding-text-to-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence of multiple white space characters is collapsed by default in
HTML,  except in  some  elements  like `textarea`  inner  text like  you
noticed. You have a few options:

- Process your text to convert newlines to `<br>` tags (see [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php))
- Echo it to  an element which preserve line breaks,  such as an styled
  `<pre>`
- Use CSS to set the `white-space` of your element to `pre`, `pre-line`
  or `pre-wrap` which will respect line breaks

Comment: +1 In particular for the CSS solution. I think it makes more sense than adding extra markup to achieve the desired format.